# Why use setter and getter methods to define sth?

Tags: java

***Using Setter and Getter**

```
class sum {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  public void setSum(int a, int b) {
    c = a + b;
  } 
  public int getSum() {
    return c;
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sum s = new sum();
    s.setSum(10,7);
    System.out.println("Sum: " + s.getSum());
    }
  }
```

***Using just only one method (getter)**

```
class sum1 {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  public int getSum(int a, int b) {
    c = a+b;
    return c;
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sum1 s1 = new sum1();
    System.out.println("Sum: " + s1.getSum(7,10));
    }
  }
```

I would like to know why the teacher encouraged me to use Setter and Getter when both coding ways result the same (17)

What specific reason lies behind using Setter and Getter?

Comment: Why don't you ask your teacher?

Comment: Well there is a whole discussion that can be had on the merits of getters and setters. But looking only at your code, you first have to understand that they are really not the same. The first allows you to set values a and b at one stage, and then retrieve the sum later, without knowing a and b. Your second sample, requires you to know the values a and be at the get stage, and the class properties a and b are not used at all. (One could then just as well calculate the sum directly in the calling code)

Comment: I see. thanks all for explaining it to me

Answer (score 1):

Like visibleman said, they're not the same thing. They do what their names say, they set values and get values. Although you may not see the use of them in a small program. Their uses are noticeable in a large application where you have to modularise your code and you want to GET a value from some other class from somewhere. You wouldn't want that method to be 'SET'ting that value to something else while you're 'GET'ting the value. Do you understand?

Comment: One could argue however that the teacher has made a sort of design mistake. I think it would be more logical for the student, if the setter was called something like setTerms(t1,t2) and only modified the a,b to equal t1,t2. Then the getSum could return the sum of the a,b properties. I guess the teacher wanted to show the common pattern, where a single property has both a getter and setter, but then there are no need for the a,b member variables